# How to input an array in R script running inside QGIS

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-processing, qgis-2

I am using QGIS 2.18.21 and running an R script which needs various files as inputs. The number of files to be inputted is also entered by user. I am thinking of taking the input of all file paths in an array. I am aware that in QGIS, we must specify the type of input at the beginning of script using `##`. I have tried the following:

```
## file_arr = array
## file_array = list
```

but I got strange errors. The script didn't even run at all. For example, with a script as simple as the following:

```
##arr=array
print(arr)
```

I got the error:
[image]

and on clicking the `View mesage log`, I got the following:
[image]

Now, first of all I have no idea why is this a Python error since I am running a R script,
and secondly there is no proper documentation of how to specify the input of different R data types in QGIS.
Please help me out to take an array as input.

Answer (score 1):

1. > first of all I have no idea why is this a Python error since I am running a R script

Processing is a Python module that uses [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to run R scripts, and so, it's a Python error

2. > there is no proper documentation of how to specify the input of different R data types

You can only use the parameter types that are supported in R processing scripts ([Use R scripts in Processing](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/processing/r_intro.html)) and those of [Writing new Processing algorithms as python scripts](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html) (look at [Python headers in R scripts for QGIS](http://www.supagro.fr/ress-tice/OpenSpat/exemple/co/PythonR.html))

```
##arr=string
print(arr)
```

Examine the example scripts of [QGIS-Processing/rscripts/](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/tree/master/rscripts) for example